# How do I skip header row using Python glcoud.bigquery client?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a daily GCP billing export file in csv format containing GCP billing details. This export contains a header row. I've setup a load job as follows (summarized):

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
job = client.load_table_from_storage(job_name, dest_table, source_gs_file)
job.source_format = 'CSV'
job.skipLeadingRows=1
job.begin()
```

This job produces the error:

Could not parse 'Start Time' as a timestamp. Required format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:SS[.SSSSSS]]

This error means that it is still trying to parse the header row even though I specified skipLeadingRows=1. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `skip_leading_rows` instead of `skipLeadingRows` when using the Python SDK.

> skip_leading_rows: Number of rows to skip when reading data (CSV only).

Reference: https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.LoadJobConfig.html

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this. I took the example you gave ("2017-02-04T00:00:00-08:00"), added 3 rows/timestamps to a csv file, uploaded it to GCS, and finally created an empty table in BigQuery with one column of type `TIMESTAMP`.

File contents:

```
2017-02-04T00:00:00-08:00
2017-02-03T00:00:00-08:00 
2017-02-02T00:00:00-08:00
```

I then ran the example Python script found [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/cloud-client/load_data_from_gcs.py), and it successfully loaded the file into the table:

> Loaded 3 rows into timestamp_test:gcs_load_test.

```
def load_data_from_gcs(dataset_name, table_name, source):
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
    dataset = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_name)
    table = dataset.table(table_name)
    job_name = str(uuid.uuid4())

    job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_storage(job_name, table, source)

    job.begin()

    wait_for_job(job)

    print('Loaded {} rows into {}:{}.'.format(job.output_rows, dataset_name, table_name))
```

[image]

Comment: Aha...so it's not the T separator. My bad! Thanks for taking this on Graham and proving me wrong. I missed the real issue which is pointed out in the first part of the error message which states: "Could not parse 'Start Time' as a timestamp". 'Start Time' is from the CSV header row. I've included 'job.skipLeadingRows = 1' in my script, but that doesn't seem to be working. Why isn't the job skipping that header row?

Comment: Note that I have revised my original question based on Graham's helpful feedback.

Comment: Great, so it's something else then. Cool. However, just for future reference, it's not a great idea to completely edit the original question and turn it into a new one, because my answer is now totally irrelevant. It's better to spin off a new question from the original, and mark this one as solved.